# How to pass a character as arguments of a function in R?

Tags: r

Normally, we can write a following function in R:

```
testFunc <- function(a) {a} # This returns the value of a
```

such that

```
testFunc(1)

1
```

How can we get the testFunc in this way:

```
argName <- 'a'

testFunc <- function(argName) {a} # This does not work, since argName is required in this function.
```

Comment: what do you mean for `a` as return value in `testFunc <- function(argName) {a}`?

Comment: Hi Bowen Chen, do you want to return the default argument? If so, formals does this formals(testFunc)$a

Answer (score 1):

```
#create function without arguments
testFunc <- function() {a}

#add argument
argName <- 'a'
args <- alist(x = )
names(args) <- argName
formals(testFunc) <- args

testFunc
#function (a) 
#{
#  a
#}
```